# Why do I see 我 for I, but is pronounced WAH

Tags: pronunciation

I'm corrected to pronounce WAH instead of "wǒ."

Is it the same and I just hear it wrong in my head? Or is there a difference in dialect?

Comment: Who corrects you? Or where do you hear 我 being pronounced as "wah"? Can you add more context and details? Thank you. :)

Comment: It could potentially be a different dialect - 我 in Taiwanese is pronounced "wah"

Comment: @pyko exactly what I was coming here to say.

Although when I first started learning Mandarin, I always heard things differently than how people were saying them - so it could just as easily be that as well.

Comment: By the way, on the same note, I noticed that in an audio file I have 好 (hăo) is pronounced "hău", but I guess it's just a matter of that pronunciation, maybe very exaggerated.

Comment: When I first started learning, my Taiwan friend would correct my pronunciation, after a while I realised I should ignore him, and follow standard Mandarin.

Comment: Is the "o" in 我 (wo） and 波 （bo) the same sound?

Answer (score 5):

I made a little search in forvo.com, a worldwide database that hosts user-provided audios for words, characters and expressions in every language.

Making a quick search for 我, [the results](http://it.forvo.com/word/%E6%88%91/) reveal several entries. The obvious ones Chinese and Japanese and others; among the others we have [Min nan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_Nan) (Simpl: 闽南语; Trad: 閩南語; pinyin: Mǐnnán Yǔ), which is a family of Chinese language spoken in: *China (PRC and ROC areas), Malaysia, Indonesia, Singapore, Thailand, Philippines, Vietnam, United States (New York City), and other areas of Southern Min and Hoklo settlement.*<sup>1</sup>

If you go to the "results" link, and scroll down until you find "min nan", you'll see it's pronounced "wah". It's unambiguous, it's pronounced very open so you can't be mistaken when you find it. I checked the others and no-one else seems to say "wah".

---

<sup>1: definition, chinese version and locations are taken from Wikipedia.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Don't rely on English phonetics.  Pinyin shouldn't be read as if it were English.  In a sense, especially with regard to vowels, Pinyin is more like Spanish or other Romance languages.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a native speaker. It is "wǒ" in Mandarin. When my parents speak in Taiwanese, it sounds more like "wah".

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the question for me, since I'm from Malaysia :p

So, **"wah"** is not really a 闽南语
but [Hokkien 福建話](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokkien), it carry the meaning of **me**

In Taiwan 闽南语, **me** = 阮 (pronunce similar to wound, without the `d`)

Comment: 福建话属于闽南语。台语也属于闽南语。

Comment: not really, both languages are very similar

Comment: [闽南语](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_Chinese) is a language group that _includes_ several distinct dialects (or languages--I'm not qualified to say). Wikipedia lists 泉州话、漳州话、台湾话、潮州话、厦门话. I'm not claiming that both Taiwanese and whatever variety you speak are the same.

Comment: "I" is pronounced as "wah" in Teochew (Chaozhou) dialect

Answer (score 1):

The standard pronunciation in Mandarin should be wǒ. "Wah" could be from some dialect in southern China.

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide a source for your claim that 'Wah' comes from a southern dialect. It is important to provide facts.